# Source Binding in WPF like Asp.Net

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a transaction table to store all the transaction happened on a single day. I wrote query as

```
select CurrencyCode,TransactionCode,TransactionAmount,COUNT(TransactionCode) as 
[No. Of Trans] from TransactionDetails where CAST(CurrentTime as date)=CAST(GETDATE()as date)
group by TransactionCode, CurrencyCode,TransactionAmount order by CurrencyCode
```

I got the out put like this

```
CurrencyCode      TransactionCode      TransactionAmount   No.OfTrans
  ARS                 SCN                   12                 1
  AWG                 BNT                   12                 1
  BAM                 BNT                   12                 1
  BND                 BNT                   7                  1
  BWP                 BTC                   45                 1
  EUR                 BCN                   6.6                1
  EUR                 BNT                   90                 1
  EUR                 BNT                   200                1
  JPY                 BNT                   10000              2
  VND                 BNT                   600                1
  VND                 BNT                   800                1
  VND                 BNT                   10000000           1
```

But as per my requirements I want to show like this on a page for reporting purpose

```
                       ARS
BNT        0            0
BCN        0            0
SCN        1            12
BTC        0            0
STC        0            0
SNT        0            0
                     -------
Total Balance  --->    70000
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                       VND
BNT        3           10001400
BCN        0            0
SCN        0            0
BTC        0            0
STC        0            0
SNT        0            0
                     -------
Total Balance  --->    17090
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Is there any way that I can do source binding like asp.net. Design a pattern in grid and apply looping as per my Currency code. So that I can achieve like my requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create a class the represents a f.e a row in listview:

```
public class CurrencyClass
{
       public string CurrencyCode {get;set;}
       public string TransactionCode {get;set;}
       public string TransactionAmount {get;set;}
       public string NoOfTrans {get;set;}
}
```

Then let's create a DataContext class which owns a collection and methods regarding listview.

```
public class CurrencyViewModel
{
       public CurrencyViewModel()
       {
              ListOfCurrency = new ObservableCollection<CurrencyClass>();
       }

       public ObservableCollection<CurrencyClass> ListOfCurrency;
}
```

Because list is type of ObservableCollection, it will automatically notify your ListView if it's collection changes.

Now we need to create a ListView which represents your table:

```
<ListView Name="CurrencyListView">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                          <GridViewColumn Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding TransactionCode}" Header="" />
                          <GridViewColumn Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding NoOfTrans}" Header="" />
                          <GridViewColumn Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding TransactionAmount}" Header="" />
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
```

Now let's Bind ListView and ViewModel together in for example in your Window constructor:

```
CurrencyViewModel currencyViewModel = new CurrencyViewModel();
CurrencyListView.DataContext = currencyViewModel;
CurrencyListView.ItemsSource = currencyViewModel.CurrencyListView;
```

Now all you need to do is to add items to currencyViewModel.CurrencyListView and it will be shown in your ListView. Remember to change values of GridViewColumn for your purposes.